# Python/C++ extension. On import, I get an undefined symbol error

Tags: linux, python, root, c++

My setup.py and UserMethods.cpp file are below.

My issue is this: I am trying to create and install a python package using `distutils` and I am running into some issues.

When I run `python3 setup.py install --user` there is no issue. It compiles and creates a `build/` directory with a file named `lib.linux-x86_64-3.6`. When I check my `.local/lib/python3.6/site-pacages` directory, there is a file named `UserMethods.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

The issue comes when I try to import the package:

```
$ python3
>>> import UserMethods
```

which returns the following error:

```
ImportError: ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/UserMethods.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12NA62Analysis4Core18AnalyzerIdentifierD1Ev
```

I do not know how or where such a symbol would be defined or why it would be created. Does anyone have insight as to where this error is coming from? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
here is the setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

UM_module = Extension('UserMethods', sources=['UserMethodsModule.cpp'], language='C++',
                        include_dirs=[ ...many... ],
                        extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
                        libraries=['stdc++'],)

setup(name='UserMethods',
      version='1.0',
      ext_modules=[UM_module],
      )
```

and here is my UserMethods.cpp file:

```
#include <Python.h>
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include "UserMethods.hh"



/*   OUR FUNCTIONS GO HERE   */

static PyObject* UM_test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
        const char *command;
        int sts;
        if ( !PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command) ){
                return NULL;
        }
        sts = system(command);
        return PyLong_FromLong(sts);
}




static PyMethodDef UserMethods[] = {

        {"system", UM_test, METH_VARARGS, "execute shell command."},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}

};

static struct PyModuleDef UserMethodsModule = {

        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "UserMethods",
        NULL,
        -1,
        UserMethods

};



PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_UserMethods(void){

        return PyModule_Create(&UserMethodsModule);

}
```

Comment: What is the content of `UserMethods.cpp` and `setup.py`? This looks like an incompatibility between the compiler you used to compile your library and the compiler used to compile python.

Comment: The symbol is the mangled version of `NA62Analysis::Core::AnalyzerIdentifier::~AnalyzerIdentifier()`  (source: `c++filt`)

Comment: @Holt I added the requested code.  I tried commenting out the `#include UserMethods.hh` line and everything compiled fine. I think it has something to do with how the compiler imports the modules?

Comment: Is there a specific order in which I should write my "include_dirs" list? I have ~20 include directories

Comment: @DaneCross Apparently you are using `NA62Analysis`, so you likely need to add to your PATH the required dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Holt above, this error was caused by not importing the library that contains the type definition in the error.

I had to add the path to the library in my linking step, which I added to the 'extra_link_args' argument in the Extension function call in Setup.py.

Comment: can you post the setup.py code change required?